# Allow sudo su - only to one user

Tags: security, sudo, openldap

Allow sudo su - on visudo only to one or some users of a group that access by ldap

For example, I have visually defined the following:

```
% dev ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

What I need is that only some users or only one of the dev group can do the sudo su -, not all of the group ... is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you create a new group?

Comment: Just use `username` instead of `%dev`.  eg I have `sweh ALL=(ALL) ALL` on my machine to allow the user "sweh" all commands.

Comment: Related to `sudo su -`: [Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169)

Comment: yes but in my case I need the sweh user to be in the group% dev which is authenticated by openldap